# сравнение ссылочных переменных типа String

Tags: java, android, строки, типы-данных

Подскажите, как в данном случае работает компилятор? Интересует как сравнивается ссылка объекта `str1` с `(str2+str3)`? `str1` в данном случае - ссылка на Объект String, а что есть `(str2+str3)`?

```
String str1 = "name";
String str2 = "name";
String str3 = "";
System.out.println(str1==(str2+str3) ? "true" : "false");
```

Результатом работы будет `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор `=` в данном случае сравнивает ссылки на объекты, и соответственно `str1` и `str2+str3` даст `false`. Если хотите получить `true`, как равные строки, то применяйте метод `equals()`, который в классе `String` переопределен на этот случай. Неплохое объяснение [тут](http://javagu.ru/portal/dt?last=false&provider=javaguru&ArticleId=GURU_ARTICLE_92913&SecID=GURU_SECTION_63111)

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю как сравнить по значению два объекта. Интересует именно данная ситуация, ссылка от str1 будет сравниваться с чем? Что есть (str2+str3) в данном примере?

Comment: В результате конкатенации строк будет создан новый объект, Java сравнит один и тот же ли это объект, и когда поймет что нет - вернет false

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант можно убедиться в этом используя сравнение через .itern. Т.е. str1.intern()==(str2+str3).intern()